# overlay content retains scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, overlay

I have googled and fiddled with this for hours!

I have a map that is using an image map for states that when clicked produces an overlay that shows (from the database via AJAX) all of the universities in that state that we serve and the properties serving each university...works fine!

However, if you scroll within the overlay on one state, close that state and click on another state, the second states listing shows with the same offset of the scrolling for the first state (wow, that doesn't sound confusing, right?).

What I need is a solution to ensure that each overlay will appear with the TOP of the listing at the top of the DIV in which it appears.

if seeing the page helps, it is in development at http://dev.edrtrust.com/myownapt/index.php/conn/index.

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No plugin required. Just change **line 19** of the page you linked to as follows:

```
$('#stateListing').empty().append(data).scrollTop(0);
```

The `scrollTop(0)` tagged on the end there should do the trick.

**Update:** If that's not working, you may need to shift `$('#stateListing').scrollTop(0);` around, either just before or just after `$.post()` to see what works.

Comment: nope ... If I click on California and scroll to the end of that listing then close the overlay and click on Florida ... the list is still offset. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @jgravois What browser are you using? I use Chrome and it jumps back to the top for me.

Comment: Firefox ... but it works great in Chrome, IE7 and IE8 (now that's a change from the norm)

Answer (score 0):

How about this plugin?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Comment: I must admit that I didn't consider a plug-in nor did I look into them. I figured it could be done with the core functionality. I will check this out.